# Best practices for scheduling multiple jobs at different frequencies in a Python project?

Tags: python, launchd, project-organization

I have started scheduling a couple scripts in Python using launchd. All my imports are from the root directory, though, so unless I want to mess with sys.path (which feels like poor practice) I need to put this scheduled script in my root directory.

There are a few other scripts I want to automate, too, at varying frequencies (one hourly, one daily, etc.).

So right now, it seems like my two options are:

1. Filling up my root directory with scheduled scripts (clean sys.path, ugly project organization)
2. Storing scheduled scripts in a subfolder, but editing sys.path in each one (ugly sys.path, clean organization)

**Is there a better alternative?** Both of these seem to be suboptimal solutions. Thanks in advance for any help/advice!!

Comment: "I need to put this scheduled script in my root directory" in general, you can just add the directory of the script to your system's PYTHONPATH environment variable if you want to avoid editing `sys.path`.

Comment: I specified the root directory for PYTHONPATH in the environment variables of my .plist file and it's working now!